# Restlet getIdentifier() Error

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

When I tried to execute the "FirstResource" Example :

> http://restlet.org/learn/2.0/firstResource

I have an error in this line caused by ***getIdentifier()***:

> itemResource = new ClientResource(r.getIdentifier());

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a hint: post the error you got.

Comment: The error is that "***The method getIdentifier() is undefined for the type Representation***".

I have the same message for the ***setIdentifier(String)*** method.

Comment: I've tested this code using the Restlet 2.0.15 release, and get no error.
May I ask you what kind of Restlet release are you using? Best regards,
Thierry Boileau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this method has been replaced by Representation#getLocationRef

Answer (score 0):

there're some changes between restlet2.1.2 and restlet2.0.*, you can read the example in your install path\src\org.restlet.example package, then you will find the changed points between the two editions!